# gcc warning about unitialized values caused by turning optimization on

Tags: c++, initialization, compiler-optimization, temporary-objects

Consider the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename Value>
struct Wrapper {
    Value m_value;

    Wrapper() {}
    Wrapper(const Wrapper<Value> &copy_from) : m_value(copy_from.m_value) {}
};

template<typename Value>
struct DefaultContainer {
    Value m_default;

    DefaultContainer(const Value& def) : m_default(def) {}
};

template<typename Value>
struct DefaultContainerUser : public DefaultContainer<Value> {
    DefaultContainerUser() : DefaultContainer<Value>(Value()) {}
};

int main() {
    DefaultContainerUser<Wrapper<double>> user;
    std::cout << user.m_default.m_value << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile this with `c++ -O1 -Werror -Wall test.cpp`, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:63: error: ‘<anonymous>.Wrapper<double>::m_value’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
    8 |  Wrapper(const Wrapper<Value> &copy_from) : m_value(copy_from.m_value) {}
      |                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

If I disable optimizations using `-O0`, everything works fine. Adding `-Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized` with optimizations still turned on doesn't help. What am I doing wrong here?

The compiler that I'm using is `c++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20201016 (Red Hat 10.2.1-6)`.

Comment: Where is `copy_from.m_value` initialized?

Comment: Ah, you are right, changing the default constructor to `Wrapper() : m_value() {}` fixes the problem. Sometime you just need somebody to re-read the error message to you. But why do I only get the error with optimizations turned on?

Comment: I guess it's a consequence of UB - it can show up in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Some debug builds initialize memory to zero, which probably interfere with unitialized usage detection.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that the warnings reported by a compiler varies depending on the optimization level. Warnings are usually a bi-product of optimization in the sense that the analysis needed for a particular optimization may uncover possible problems in the code or that transformations applied during optimization may uncover possible errors. This implies that when optimization is off and the analysis and transformations are not performed the problems are not detected.